# counting function calls in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Hi I am looking for a method to count function calls in clojure so that for instance I can find out which functions are called most frequently. Ideally I would like this to be transparent to users so that if they add a function they don't know or care about this process. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanking you in advance
Michael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the call count in an [`atom`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/atom) and attach an accessor to the function using [`with-meta`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-meta):

```
(def sqrt
  (let [n (atom 0)]
    (with-meta
      (fn [x]
        (swap! n inc)
        (Math/sqrt x))
      {::call-count (fn [] @n)})))
```

Examples:

```
((::call-count (meta sqrt))) ;=> 0

(sqrt 0)                     ;=> 0.0
(sqrt 1)                     ;=> 1.0
(sqrt 2)                     ;=> 1.4142135623730951

((::call-count (meta sqrt))) ;=> 3

(sqrt 3)                     ;=> 1.7320508075688772
(sqrt 4)                     ;=> 2.0
(sqrt 5)                     ;=> 2.23606797749979

((::call-count (meta sqrt))) ;=> 6
```

This may cause considerable slowdown in some cases, but the count will always be updated correctly because Clojure atoms are thread-safe. Another approach could be to use [`add-watch`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/add-watch) rather than [`deref`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref), but which one is better depends on your situation. You could even use both if you want to.

You can abstract away the details with a `defcounted` macro to define call-counted functions and a `call-count` function to retrieve the call count of a call-counted function:

```
(defmacro defcounted [sym params & body]
  `(def ~sym
     (let [n# (atom 0)]
       (with-meta
         (fn ~params
           (swap! n# inc)
           ~@body)
         {::call-count (fn [] @n#)}))))

(defn call-count [f]
  ((::call-count (meta f))))

(defcounted sqrt [x]
  (Math/sqrt x))
```

Examples:

```
(call-count sqrt) ;=> 0

(sqrt 0)          ;=> 0.0
(sqrt 1)          ;=> 1.0
(sqrt 2)          ;=> 1.4142135623730951

(call-count sqrt) ;=> 3

(sqrt 3)          ;=> 1.7320508075688772
(sqrt 4)          ;=> 2.0
(sqrt 5)          ;=> 2.23606797749979

(call-count sqrt) ;=> 6
```

Also, since here you're attaching the metadata to the function itself rather than to the var, you could expand this technique to anonymous functions as well.

Obviously `defcounted` is lacking a lot of [`defn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defn)'s features, so it's not really transparent to the user. In fixing this problem, you could use [`clojure.spec`](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) to more easily parse the `defn`-style arguments, but I'll leave that for you to do as you see fit, as it's orthogonal to this question.